# Edit the Title Text on the site to remove any suggestion that questions about career building are on-topic here

Tags: feature-request, scope

Right now, the site's title text contains this tagline:

> Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers

…and while of this is all *incidentally* true, [a developer who asks a question about career development will immediately get shot down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381630/where-should-i-ask-programming-advice-and-career-related-questions) because that ain't what we're about.

I think this needs to be reworded—or, preferably, just removed.

Comment: But what about *Developer Stories* and the *Jobs* section?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Inconsequential; Jobs already has its own title text, and your Developer Story is an extension of your profile, so it doesn't have any of that flowery language.

Comment: But it's part of the Stack Overflow site, so I can see why it is part of the title of the homepage.

Comment: *"Where Developers Get Answers and Find Jobs"* (or "Careers", doesn't matter)

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  I wonder if it's worth an A/B test to see if the title text would make that much of a material difference on the traffic to the Jobs site.  I'd be open to that, honestly.

Comment: Just to clarify, which thing are we not about: immediately shooting down developers, or asking questions about career development?

Comment: Career development @CodyGray.  Although one can beget the other.

Comment: On top of the problem OP described there is another (very very subtle) issue: I'm not a native English speaker, and in my mother tongue (a Romance language) all those three verbs (to learn, to share and to build) can be regarded as having "careers" as complement: *"Where Developers Learn Careers, Share Careers, & Build Careers"*. I reckon that the same thing happens in English as well. So, yes, that should be reworded to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado maybe be explicit about what to *Learn* and *Share* then? "*Where Developers Learn Programming, Share Code & Build Careers*"

Comment: @Lino, yes, you got my point. But I have to confess that I don't like that *share* in the original text... S.O. is not a platform to "share code", which seems a GitHub-like site, do you agree? Maybe this: *"Where Developers Learn Programming, Share Knowledge & Build Careers"*. By the way, kudos for removing that comma before the ampersand! While in English a comma before an ampersand is not grammatically wrong in a list with 3 or more elements, I really don't like it!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes I agree completely, the *Share* is not meant for code, but for knowledge. See: Even I don't know what the *Share* meant, how should a new visitor then understand what *Share* means :) Time to clarify this title.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado "Learn programming" is the wrong connotation too, in my eyes. We are not a tutorial or practice site, but a Q&A site. Yes, getting your questions answered can be of immense _help_ while learning programming, but I see no overarching goal of _teaching_ programming in that sense.

Comment: There's a half-meme going around about how the text should change which I am loathe to stop, but I'm really just advocating for the wholesale removal of any of that text.  The less language there is, the less ambiguity there is.

Comment: Can I just point out that it is wrong to put a comma before an ampersand?  People are trying to transfer the Oxford comma to the ampersand, and it doesn't go there.  To be explicit, in a list of three or more ", and" is perfectly correct (and IMO preferable) but it should always be simply "&".  The ", &" is never correct.  Not under any circumstance other than talking about commas (e.g. ";, , & :" might be correct if confusing to read:  "semi-colons, commas, and colons").

Comment: @mdfst13: It wouldn't be confusing if it were removed.

Comment: I have to point out, with the recent (IMO unfortunate) trend towards browsers ditching title bars, unless I hover over the tab the text cuts off and I only see, at best (even with no other tabs open) *"Stack Overflow - Where developer"*; at this point I'm not sure there's any currently supported browser where you'd see the full text other than IE or some browsers on Linux (e.g., Chromium) with customized settings. As much as I used to like descriptive page titles, I'd say give up and just have the page title be "Stack Overflow", most page hits will be on questions anyway.

Comment: @jrh It doesn't only appear on title bars, [the result from Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow) also includes the tagline under question. [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=stackoverflow) shows "Stack Overflow - Official Site". [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow&ia=web) shows "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn ... - Learn, Share, Build". While the question only concerns the title text, if we're for removing the tagline then what will become of the search results? Perhaps go with Bing's "Stack Overflow - Official Site"?

Comment: @TrebledJ Ah right, I forgot about Google Search results. Good point.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Something like *Donde programadores aprender, compartir, y construir las carreras*? With my past experience in learning English, I'd say +1 for your point because that's what comma-separated verbs often imply to readers.